# Get id_product in a hook from a module (Prestashop 1.7)

Tags: javascript, ajax, module, prestashop, hook

I would like to recover the product id to be able to make my ajax call which needs the product id of the current product page. So I use the hook displayProductAdditionnalInfo which correctly returns the id_product to me but when I try to call it in another method, it returns me false.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNwMO.png)

Can you help me? Is there a solution or an alternative ?

Comment: This could happen because Tools:getValue() will read data from GET or POST , so you'll need to inside a product page when calling the hook from your function.  If not, you must retrieve the product data from the context object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to recover via the cart present in the context

```
$listingProduct = Context::getContext()->cart->getProducts();
```

Regards

Comment: Yes I tried but the problem is that I get the correct product but only if it is in the cart.
Except me I want it back even if it’s not in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Tools::getValue recovers data from $_POST and $_GET.

If you do not persist info in http request, you can use cookies.

When you get id_product you can save in cookies:

```
Context::getContext()->cookie->my_product_id = $your_desired_id_product;
```

When you need id_product just

```
$your_desired_id_product = Context::getContext()->cookie->my_product_id;
```

Remember to check if cookie value exists

```
isset(Context::getContext()->cookie->my_product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the product id from the hook method to the desired method,
or you can create an attribute $product_id and set it in the hook method and call it in the desired method as $this->product_id